# kong api gateway is not working in GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kong, gke-networking

kong api gateway is not working in GKE cluster with kong proxy and self signed certificate

I am following below doc to create kong api gateway with self signed certificate but its not working,
https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.7.x/guides/using-gateway-api/

getting unknow gatewayclass and there is no IP address generated for gateway,

Is kong api gateway with self signed certificate support in GKE Cluster,

Comment: share the error you are getting i am running kong in GKE without self singed cert but it's working well with let's encrypt cert. also did you check gateway class setup ?

Comment: @HarshManvar getting below error:
    Message:               Waiting for controller
    Reason:                Waiting
    Status:                Unknown

Comment: @HarshManvar 
I also tried to setup kong with controller and proxy in GKE, its working with kong proxy IP, able to access the MS application without cert but when using self signed certificate after enabling kong-proxy-tls secret and secret volume then its showing different server certificate during MS API call using kong proxy ip and getting failed, seems default kong controller certificate,
Also tried to create CSR and approved it and then tried to get certificate from CSR to create secret then not getting certificate from CSR,

Comment: self signed certificates are not recommended on public cloud networks. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67862059/1891047 I think it is better to have proper defined certificate in this scenario.